# Where to put JAR containing custom ant task?

Tags: ant

I've created a custom ant task according to Apache doc.

Running ant, I get:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/russ/blackpearl/fun/build.xml:92: taskdef class com.etretatlogiciels.ant.task.SqlScriptPreprocessor cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

I have the following in *build.xml* prior to my use of

```
<taskdef name="sqlscriptpreprocessor" classname="com.etretatlogiciels.ant.task.SqlScriptPreprocessor" />
```

...and I've dropped a copy of *sqlscriptpreprocessor.jar* into my local lib subdirectory (should be on classpath) and even into */usr/bin/ant/lib* (which is apache-ant-1.8.2).

Where should this go? Or what other problems are anticipated that I should look for?

Thanks very much for any and all comments.

Russ

Comment: What do you mean "local lib directory"?

Comment: The lib subdirectory that's on my build classpath and contains all the JARs I'm linking against (like Hibernate, log4j, Jersey, MySQL, Spring, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try nesting

```
<classpath>
<pathelement location="C:\**\**.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

Inside the taskdef, e.g.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="C:\myfolder\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath> 
</taskdef>
```

Ideally it should pick up from ant/lib, but specifying **pathelement** forces it to look in the given path.

Comment: Well, I fiddled with this, added six different incantations of the ant-contrib stuff and three different of my own, tried every permutative combination thereof, and now always fail with "Problem: failed to create task or type sqlscriptpreprocessor" For it being "really easy" to add an ant task, I sure can't seem to do it. Since this isn't the error based on which I asked this question, I'm going to submit a new one here. Thanks for your help; I'll come back an annotate this response once I gain a clear understanding of how to do this stuff.